# The -nodeprecated option in javadoc doesn't seem to work. What can I do?

Tags: java, javadoc, deprecated

I have a deprecated method in my class:

```
@Deprecated
public void deprecatedMethod() {
   //do bad things
}
```

I don't want that method to appear in the javadoc.
I know there's an option called [-nodeprecated](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#nodeprecated) which:

> "Prevents the generation of any
>   deprecated API at all in the
>   documentation."

So I'm using this option and it doesn't exclude the method from javadoc. Is it a bug in javadoc or am I using it wrong? What else can I do?

(I'm using eclipse 3.4.2 to produce javadoc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include "-nodeprecated" option in the Export to javadoc wizard.
Warning: it is a javadoc option, not a VM option.

I've tested it in Eclipse 3.4 and it worked.

**Edit:** If you only include Deprecated annotation it doesn't work. You have to include @deprecated tag inside method javadoc as well.

I don't know if there's a way to tell javadoc to use @Deprecated anotation (which curiously doesn't have a message parameter to document why is deprecated and what else to use).

**Edit:** before-1.5 way of deprecate methods

You have to include a @deprecated tag (or indicator or whatever) with the message you want to display to the user in the javadoc after the "**deprecated**".

```
/**
  This method sets the property A.
  @see getA
  @author helios
  @deprecated This method is not sync safe, use setAOk instead
 */
public void setA(String value) ...
```

Comment: Really? That's exactly what I did. Still doesn't work...
Have you marked your class @Deprecated the same way I did?
How did you generate javadoc? Here's how I did:
Project->Generate Javadoc->next->next.
and there in the extra javadoc options I wrote -nodeprecated.

Comment: Let me try, I've used javadoc @deprecated also :)

Comment: OK. What does it mean to "include @deprecated tag inside method javadoc"? How? (and thanks)

Comment: I suspect that javadoc only process what's inside the /** **/ and doesn't look for annotations... I checked the javadoc -help and it doesn't says nothing about annotations. Only the -nodeprecated and the -nodeprecatedlist (don't generate the list of deprecated methods altogether).

Answer (score 0):

@helios

john is saying that you must include the @deprecated javadoc tag within the javadoc comment block (/** ... */) as he has done above with:

```
@deprecated This method is not sync safe, use setAOk instead
```

Add this, then use the -nodeprecated option when running javadoc and the methods will not appear in the generated doc.